# error 404 after login in frontend for SOME users

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm facing a really strange issue with Magento. 
Basically some users can login and interact with the site normally, and others login but end up with a 404 error on every page...

I've tried tweaking the cookies settings via Magento backend and also thru database. Exported and imported again the users, changed the session location from db to file... disabled cache, cleared cache, deleted everything from /var/ but nothing seem to help. And no errors are thrown anywhere.

I've also checked the session files for these users and they seem be fine.

I've noticed in the session files, that there's a brief history of the user... I was thinking if there are some tables where this data is coming from and that I can clear and see if it works.

I'm lost, really. And out of ideas!

Comment: Have you checked the site permissions for each user?

Comment: @smiggle can you explain, please?!?

Comment: Do you have a plugin like geoip or something similar ? Is there a technology common point (eg : OS, device) ?

Comment: @ChristopheFerreboeuf: I do server rewrites (mod rewrite) based on the browser language... I've tried with all browsers on OS X, on both iMac and MacBooks old and new, and it acts the same... not tried on windows, but I guess it's the same.